# getRange(a1Notation) not found issue

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I try to get a range which is determined by an argument of the function:

```
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var range = ss.getRange("Test!A1:D"+row);
```

And there I get an error "range not found".
The range notation is good, when I log it in console it shows

```
Test!A1:D4
```

After I replace the code with

```
var range = ss.getRange("Test!A1:D4");
```

everything works great.
Where is the mistake?
Funny thing that some time ago it worked great.

Comment: Could you also post the code related to `row` ?

Comment: It's an argument of the function called from the cell. Here it was `function testGetRange(row){}` And the call is `testGetRange(4)`.

Comment: How about ``ss.getRange("A1:D"+row)`` and ``ss.getRange("'Test'!A1:D"+row)``? Unfortunately, in my environment, it cannot reproduce your situation. So if these didn't work yet, can you provide a sample spreadsheet?

Comment: Those didn't work either (I tested it before) but! Suddenly the error just disappeared. It looks like the document got refreshed (I did nothing for a longer while) and after that the function works fine.

Comment: Thank you for your additional information. Also the reload of the document might become one of solutions?

Comment: Yes, reloading cures the problem but refreshing did not.

Answer (score 1):

Very doable, just make sure you reload your google sheet when making changes on a [container-bound script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound). I can even use sheet name as variable in the sheet range.

```
function fetchActiveRow(){  
     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
     var row = ss.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange().getRow();
     var sheetName = ss.getActiveSheet().getSheetName();
     var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
     var range = ss.getRange( sheetName+"!A1:B"+row );
     var response = ui.alert( "range is " + range );
}
```